# In 10.3 System DialogInput execution error

Tags: warning-messages, button, version-10.3

I have upgraded to 10.3 from *Mathematica* 9.0.
However, in 9.0 things that ran well will not run in 10.3.

A typical example is:

```
Button["Import File", Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", ".txt"], "List"]]
```

The code above runs in 9.0, but an error is generated in 10.3.
I wonder whether in 10.3 the method used has changed which causes  *Mathematica* to emit the error.

The error message is:

> SystemDialogInput::nprmtv: SystemDialogInput is not currently supported within preemptive evaluations. >>

Comment: As the answers given below point out, V10.3 is simply being smarter than V9. So it's not a bug, but an improvement.

Answer (score 8):

Add `Method -> "Queued"`

```
Button["Import File", Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", ".txt"], "List"], 
 Method -> "Queued"]
```

From [IntroductionToControlObjects](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToControlObjects.html)

> So if you have an evaluation that you expect will take more than a
>   couple of seconds to evaluate, you should use Method->"Queued".
>   Clicking such a button will use the main link when evaluating its
>   function, and that evaluation will be queued along with evaluations
>   queued using Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 7):

> The code above 9.0 is good

Unfortunately, this is not true. Even in version 9 this code was not good, but it just did not warn you about it. Take this simpler example, that only prints the file-name of the selected file and try it in version 9:

```
Button["Import File", Print[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]]]
```

If you try the button and select a file quickly, then it will print the file-name. If you need more than some seconds to select the file, it doesn't print the file-name. The reason is that *preemtive evaluations* have a timeout to not block the user interface.

Therefore, if you have a button with an action that takes longer, you need to use the option

```
Method->"Queued"
```

even in version 9. In version 10.3, *Mathematica* just doesn't allows for this error and warns you.